# MySQL subselect in query

Tags: mysql

I would like to get the following results from my query:

```
id_product_attribute | id_product | reference | name         | total
12                   | 1          | 234235    | product_name | 2
14                   | 2          | 235435    | product_name | 7
16                   | 3          | 235325    | product_name | 4
```

etc

but when I use this query:

```
select pa.id_product_attribute, p.id_product, pa.reference, cl.name, sum(od.product_quantity) as total
from ps_product_attribute pa
left join ps_order_detail od on od.product_attribute_id = pa.id_product_attribute
left join ps_product p on pa.id_product = p.id_product
left join ps_category_product cp on cp.id_product = p.id_product
left join ps_category_lang cl on cp.id_category = cl.id_category
where cp.id_category = 141 and cl.id_lang = 6;
```

it gives me only this results:

```
id_product_attribute | id_product | reference | name         | total
12                   | 1          | 234235    | product_name | 13
```

so in the 'total' column it shows me the total of all, instead of seperate per row.

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source data would help, but at the very least you forgot to `GROUP BY` at the end. With the current query, you should add;

```
GROUP BY pa.id_product_attribute, p.id_product, pa.reference, cl.name
```

With MySQL, you can choose to `GROUP BY` less columns and get a random selection of values in the other ones, but if possible, you should `GROUP BY` all columns that don't have aggregates (like `SUM` in this case) on them.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions should be used with `GROUP BY` CLAUSE